# Openshift redhat nodejs server times out on scaling

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, redhat, scaling

My application crashes frequently while deploying and when i see the logs i get this error. Please help me understand this error and what should i do to solve this error. The repo corresponding to the code is https://github.com/dhongadeaakash/nodejs-ex

```
 --> Scaling up nodejs-mongodb-example-3 from 0 to 1, scaling down nodejs-mongodb-example-1 from 1 to 0 (keep 1 pods available, don't exceed 2 pods)
Scaling nodejs-mongodb-example-3 up to 1
  error: timed out waiting for any update progress to be made
```

Comment: Please check the logs on the deployment for nodejs-mongodb-example and put the contents here. Also look at your events in the project and see if there is any messages that might be helpful there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is relevant, but worth giving a try. Recently openshift added a requirement to add a `/health` end point to indicate your server is alive.

In recent templates (= the server that's created automatically when you create a new app) I saw the following lines:

```
app.get('/health', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
});
```

Try adding this in your code and see if it helps